# Using different UiBinder @UiTemplate files depending on module property

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I can use `<replace-with>` tags to swap out different implementations of a class depending on the properties set in my GWT module file.  That's great - I love it.

BUT: all that's different about my views between `formfactor="mobile"` and `formfactor="desktop"` are the ui.xml files I use - even the java files are identical.  So, class swapping isn't sufficient - I don't want to have to duplicate the Java files to get different classes.

How can I use properties to affect which ui.xml file is loaded as a UiBinder template?

**note**: I'm currently using a workaround that calculates what the module properties *should* be in Java, and using the property in a switch statement that loads the appropriate ui.xml file.  This is undesirable because:

- Code is duplicated - I have to calculate properties in the module file and in the java code
- Each permutation must compile every ui.xml file in order for the correct one to be chosen at runtime.  I'd prefer a compile-time solution.

Comment: Are these properties static or determined during runtime?

Comment: They are determined at compile time.  I don't even know how to reference a GWT property from my Java code directly, though - it's done automatically in GWT.create and I don't know if it's possible to replicate the functionality for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

I think, that You must write your own [generator](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#generator-implementation) which will serve different ui binder templates. Probably you can overload method [deduceTemplateFile() in UiBinderGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/rebind/UiBinderGenerator.java?r=10717#61).