# Change UiTemplate based on browser user-agent in GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt, user-agent, uibinder

I've been working on a web application that will be used by both iPads and desktop browsers. I have two UiBinder templates created that have the same fields, just rearranged differently with different CSS.

Is there a way to have GWT automatically use a different UiTemplate when a mobile browser's user-agent is detected?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290978/using-different-uibinder-uitemplate-files-depending-on-module-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to take a look at m-gwt ( http://www.m-gwt.com ). This is a mobile widget library for GWT.